# SQL Server 2016 Log Shipping and Transaction Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql

Good Morning,
I have a SQL Server 2016 that is doing Log Shipping to a DR Site. I currently want to also to Replicate (Transactional) specific Tables to another Server for Reporting Purposes.

Will there be any issues or snafu's I should be aware of? Can I have Log Shipping and Transactional Replication configured on the same Publishing Database?

Comment: We will need a lot more detail to answer your hypothesis, which is not a question. You need to formulate a proper question if you are expecting an answer from people here.

Comment: OK I guess the first question is can I have Log Shipping and Transactional Replication configured on the same Publishing Database?

Answer (score 0):

Transactional Replication and Log Shipping are totally compatible features, and both can be used on the same published database.